# How to pass SSL Certificate in Copy Data Activity in Azure Data Factory to retrieve data from Rest Api?

Tags: ssl-certificate, azure-data-factory, rest

I want to copy data from Rest API using data factory. I have passed Access token in Authorization but it showing error that "No required SSL certificate was sent". How can I pass SSL certificate while copying data from Rest API?

Comment: Could you add more information as to how and what you are trying to do with examples? Generally speaking, azure **connection string** is the way to go to access any azure resource.

Comment: Hi @mang4521, I just want to authenticate Rest Api using Client Certificate Authentication in ADF, Is there any way to pass .key and .cert files for authentication in linked service? and then retrieve data from Rest API. I am using MuleSoft Rest API which using Access token and SSL certificate for authentication.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that linked service of yours? What exactly is this linked service?

Answer (score 0):

REST connector doesn't support this. REST connector only supports these properties:
[image]

More details about REST connector, you can refer to this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest.